# Is there way to create multiple modal in bootstrap by using on click jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I currently experience problem which I don't know why the same target modal id is not opening after i click the next button. to understand well let's say I have **user 1** so when i click the name of user 1 all children of user 1 will display on the modal this is working well.

So now I have the new user which is user2. so i want to display again the children of user2. however the modal is not showing again after i click the button.

**Question:** Is there way to create a multiple modal on same target id?

**Main Problem:** Modal already dismiss after i click the second user.

I will show you guys my sample code the already created.

Note: Modal use for displaying all the result response in the jquery.

**Modal And Parent **

```
    <div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="showMoreChildren" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Downline</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="wrapper_children_click"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


@foreach($children_details ? $children_details : [] as $key  => $detail)
          <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <button class="btn btn-dark onClickShowMoreChildren" data-toggle="modal" data-attribute-each-children-id="{{$detail->id}}" data-target="#showMoreChildren">{{$key+1}}</button>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$detail->fullname}}" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon" disabled>
              </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
```

**Jquery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.onClickShowMoreChildren').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var children_id = $(this).attr('data-attribute-each-children-id');
        $.ajax({
            url:'/membership/view_more_children',
            data:{children_id:children_id},
            type:'get',
            dataType:'JSON',
            success:function(res){
                console.log(res);

                $('#myModal').modal('show');

                var html_children_clicked;
                $.each(res.children_detail,function(key,value){



                    html_children_clicked = '\
                        <div class="col-md-2">\
                            <div class="input-group">\
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">\
                                    <button class="btn btn-dark onClickShowMoreChildren" data-toggle="modal" data-attribute-each-children-id="'+value['id']+'" data-target="#showMoreChildren" >'+(key+1)+'</button>\
                                </div>\
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+value['fullname']+'" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon" disabled>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    ';

                });

                $('.wrapper_children_click').append(html_children_clicked);


            },
            error:function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Parent Foreach Result:

[image: Parent]

User 2: Note when i click this i want to show again the modal and children of user 2 will display to the modal div.

[image: Second User]

Comment: [Varying modal content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) documentation - Bootstrap.

Comment: @tao what do you mean for tthat?

Comment: It explains and exemplifies how to reuse the same modal with different contents.You don't need more modals, you need to vary the contents of the same one (and probably a loading state animation while you're changing from one content version to the other).

Comment: yup. as you can see @tao i used only 1 modal. i just appending the new content on same target id.

Comment: @tao the next append not trigger the onclick function and data-target? do you know why?

Comment: What you posted is not sufficient to recreate the bug. Please add a [mcve]. You don't have to use actual calls to a server, you can replace them with calls to functions returning promises. Just make sure the returned data is correct.